# double(?) definition of template member operators

Tags: c++, templates

if I look into < complex> header from msvc 2008, I find that each operator definition is doubled with _Other type template operation, like for example

```
_Myt& operator+=(const _Myt& _Right)
{   // add other complex
   this->_Add(_Right);
   return (*this);
}
template<class _Other> inline
_Myt& operator+=(const complex<_Other>& _Right)
{   // add other complex
   this->_Add(_Right);
   return (*this);
}
```

The question is why would not the second definition alone suffice?

PS:
It seems in gcc there is only second definition present, now I do not worry any more. :)

Comment: from the top of my head: function overloads happen before template resolution. Depending code that generically accesses `T::operator+=(const T&)` would not find it, I guess

Comment: @sehe: make this into an answer and receive +1 :)

Comment: @sehe: I'm not sure how code could legally do so. Do you have an example?

Comment: @MSalters me too. or at least not in the mood to try for a contrived example using pointer to member functions in a template method :) It was just the first thought that entered my mind.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first case also catches a right-hand-side that's *convertible* to `_Myt`.

```
class MyComplex {
   // ...
   public:
     operator std::complex<double>() const;
     operator std::complex<float>() const;
};
std::complex<double> i;
i += MyComplex(1,1); // Unambiguously uses the first form.
```